# Unable to install package python-httplib2 in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, python

I'm in the need to install the package that I mentioned in the title, but when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-httplib2
```

I get:

> "Package 'python-httplib2' has no installation candidate"

I was told to run:

```
"sudo apt-get install python" 
"sudo apt-get install python2" 
"sudo apt-get update"
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: can you provide distro name and version?

Comment: Linux kali 5.4.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.13-1kali1 (2020-01-20) X68_64 GNU/Linux @AkhilJalagam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debian package search shows these only

```
Package python-httplib2
jessie (oldoldstable) (python): comprehensive HTTP client library written for Python
0.9+dfsg-2+deb8u1 [security]: all
stretch (oldstable) (python): comprehensive HTTP client library written for Python
0.9.2+dfsg-1: all
buster (stable) (python): comprehensive HTTP client library written for Python
0.11.3-2: all
sid (unstable) (libs): A comprehensive HTTP client library written in python
0.2.0-2 [debports]: m68k sh4
```

you are using old distro `lenny` which is not available.

try to manually download a stable deb package and install it
link:
https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python-httplib2

download link:
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-httplib2/python-httplib2_0.11.3-2_all.deb

Comment: Thank you dude. This is a stupid question, but when I reach https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/python-httplib2/filelist I donnow how to install it. I searched on youtube how to, but I think that I'm not searching properly.

Comment: check that updated link. its from buster and stable one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Kali Linux 2020.1 which is based on Debian 11 codenamed bullseye which has Python 3.8 as the default Python version. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python2 ca-certificates python3-httplib2
cd ~
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-httplib2/python-httplib2_0.14.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb  
sudo apt install ./python-httplib2_0.14.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Do you really need to install python-httplib2? python-httplib2 has been upgraded to python3-httplib2 in Kali Linux 2020.1.

Comment: I get this error:

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-httplib2
(...)
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/root/Downloads/python-httplib2_0.14.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Comment: I corrected the 3rd command. Starting with the Kali Linux 2020.1 release Kali has changed to a “traditional default non-root user” model. On install, Kali will prompt you to create a non-root user that will have administrative privileges (due to its addition to the sudo group). This is the same process as other Linux distros you may be familiar with.